# How to pass multiple params of GET correctly?

Tags: angularjs

```
$http({
    url: "http://someurl.php",
    method: "GET",
    params: {topicId: $stateParams.topicId, pageNumber:2}
})
```

In my php I have tried this

```
echo $_GET["pageNumber"];
echo $_GET["topicId"];
```

and in my success callback I got the value of `topicId` but the `pageNumber` value is blank.

Comment: hows ur url looks like in request header ?

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha the url is fine. I even can get the value of $_GET["topicId"].

Comment: json_encode(array('pgNumber'=>$_GET["pageNumber"], 'topicId'=>$_GET["topicId"])); please check this instead of echos

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha I can get the value of pageNumber by putting it before $_GET[topicId], strange is it?

Comment: no i guess. did u put what i suggest in my last comment ?